# Request returned result is null after Cloudflare installation on domain

Tags: android, cloudflare, android-ion

i am developing an android application which is using a Laravel RESTful API, the problem is with Cloudflare. when ever the cloudflare being installed on server, i can't connect to the API and any sent request returns NULL

Note: i'm using ion khushi library for communicating with my REST API.
Does anyone have suggestions about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

you need to exclude the REST API from Cloudflare caching: [Using Cloudflare with your API](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200504045-Using-Cloudflare-with-your-API).

also see [How do I create a Page Rule?](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200172336-How-do-I-create-a-PageRule-)